# Efficient enumeration of subsets

Tags: algorithm, optimization, set

I'm currently working on a algorithm for an mathematical optimization problem and have to deal with the following situation.

In a lot of situations the algorithm needs to decide which subset S ⊂ N is best in this situation.
N = { 0, 1, 2, ..., 126, 127 }
|S| ∈ { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }    (size of subset is between 0 and 5)

This gives a total number of possible subsets of 265.982.833. (binom(128, 5) + binom(128, 4) + ... + binom(128, 0))

If I precalculate all possible subsets and store them in an array, then this array would have 265.982.833 entries and a memory footprint of about 1,27 GB without any optimizations and naive storage of the subsets as byte arrays.

In this case, when the algorithm needs to know which elements are in a specific subset with index i just a table lookup is required. However the huge memory requirements are not acceptable.

So my question is basically if anyone can think of an algorithm to efficiently calculate the elements in a subset based on the index i instead of requiring the precomputed array.

---

EDIT included samples:
lookupTable[0] = {}
lookupTable[1] = {0}
...
lookupTable[127] = {126}
lookupTable[128] = {127}
lookupTable[129] = {0, 1}
lookupTable[130] = {0, 2}
...
lookupTable[265982832] = {123, 124, 125, 126, 127}

Comment: I think it would be hard to answer this without knowing what criteria is used for selecting a) the cardinality of S and b) members of S.  Can the elements of `N` be computed based on their index?

Comment: Do you just want a fast and memory efficient loop (or iterator) which goes through the sets, or do you actually need to code them efficienty (why?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's straightforward to construct each subset from the preceding subset. It's also straightforward to represent a subset as a 128-bit number (although obviously most values wouldn't map onto a qualifying subset, and I don't know if the value of 128 in the question was real or just an example.) That's certainly the first approach I would use; if it works, it's all O(1) and the storage cost is not extreme (16 bytes for indices instead of 4).

If you really want to store concise indices for the subsets, I'd use the following recursion, where S(n,k) represents all the subsets (or the count of the subsets) of size ≤ k from values < n:

`s(n,0) = { {} }`
`s(n,k) = (s(n-1,k-1) ⊙ {n}) ⋃ s(n-1,k) if n ≥ k > 0`
`s(n,k) = {} if n < k`

where the operator `P ⊙ S` means "Add `S` to each element of `P`" (and therefore the result is exactly the same size as `P`). So, viewed as a counting algorithm, we get:

`S(n,0) = 1`
`S(n,k) = S(n-1,k-1) + S(n-1,k) if n ≥ k > 0`
`S(n,k) = 0 if n < k`

The second recursion can be re-expressed as:

`S(n,k) = Σni=kS(i-1,k-1)`
(which would have come out looking nicer with jsMath, grrr.)

That's another way of saying that we'll generate the sets in order by the largest element, so we start with the set `{0...k-1}`, then all the sets with `{k}` as the largest element, then all the ones with `{k+1}`, and so on. Within each group of sets, we recurse to find the `(k-1)`-sized sets, again starting with the least maximum value and working our way up to one less than the maximum value we just selected.

So we can figure out what the largest value in the indexed set for an index in `S(n,k)` by successively subtracting `S(i-1, k-1)` for `i` from `k` to `n` until the result would be negative; then we add `{i}` to the result set; reduce `k` by 1 and repeat with `n` now set to `i-1`.

If we precompute the relevant tables of `S(n,k)`, of which there are about 640 valid combinations, we can use binary search instead of iteration to find the `i` at each step, so the computation takes time `k log(n)`, which is not awful.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't tought about your first approach with the 128-bit number. Seams like this will be much better than any enumeration approach.

Comment: @Knoothe: wikipedia's explanation is more elegant than mine. And they get to use real math formulas.

Answer (score 0):

The naive implementation would use a bitmap (bitX == 1 meaning that item X is present in the set) An additional constraint would be that no more than 5 bits in the mask can be one. And it would need 128 bits to represent a set.

Using the product of primenumbers to represent the set would only need <64 bits per set (the 124...128'th primenumbers are  {124:691, 125:701, 126:709, 127:719, 128:727}, and their product will fit into 64 bits, IICC. It will still waste some bits (a good enumeration would fit into 32 bits, as the OQ showed), but it is easy to check for "overlapping" common items of two sets by means of their GCD.

Both methods would need the array of values to be sorted, and using the rank of a set inside this array as its enumeration value.